# Returning duplicate rows mysql one to many

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT pc. * , ssc. * , IF( ssc.category_id = pc.ID, '1', '0' ) AS checked
FROM property_categories pc
LEFT JOIN su_selected_categories ssc ON ssc.su_property_settings_id = 9
```

I am trying to perform a select query which finds all categories, and then sees whether one of the categories is within the other table, if it is mark it as 'checked'

What I need to be left with in this instance is 3 rows (there are 3 categories), of which 2 should be within the checked column as '1' and the remaining as '0'.

This query is returning duplicate rows and when I try to group by pc.ID it misses out one of the correct rows.

Where am I going wrong?

```
 ----------------------
 | id | category_name |
 ----------------------
 | 1  | category1     |
 ----------------------
 | 2  | category2     |
 ----------------------
 | 3  | category3     |
 ----------------------


 ---------------------------------------------
 | id | su_property_settings_id | category_id |
 ---------------------------------------------
 | 1  |                      1  |           2 |
 ----------------------------------------------
 | 2  |                      9  |           2 |
 ----------------------------------------------
 | 3  |                      9  |           1 |
 ----------------------------------------------
 ...more
```

**Updated***

What I am getting with group by pc.ID

```
ID | category_name | ID | su_property_settings_id | category_id | checked
--------------------------------------------------------------------------  
1  |    cat1       | 11 |                       9 |           2 |       0 
2  |    cat2       | 11 |                       9 |           2 |       1 
3  |    cat3       | 11 |                       9 |           2 |       0
```

What I want

```
ID | category_name | ID | su_property_settings_id | category_id | checked
--------------------------------------------------------------------------  
1  |    cat1       | 11 |                       9 |           2 |       1 
2  |    cat2       | 11 |                       9 |           2 |       1 
3  |    cat3       | 11 |                       9 |           2 |       0
```

Comment: Add to your `GROUP BY` whichever field(s) you want to not be "missed".  Which field this is isn't clear from your question, showing output you're getting and desired output would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting duplicate rows because your join is on the wrong columns.  You are not including the condition on `category_id`.  The following should fix the duplication problem:

```
SELECT pc.*, ssc.*, (ssc.category_id is not null) AS checked
FROM property_categories pc LEFT JOIN
     su_selected_categories ssc
     ON ssc.su_property_settings_id = 9 and
        ssc.category_id = pc.ID;
```

If you still have duplicates (which I doubt), then it is probably due to duplicates in the `category_id` column.

This returns `1` or `0`, depending on whether the category is every selected, rather than `'1'` and `'0'`.  Note this is different from the character values in your query.  I suspect the numeric value is more appropriate.

If you want the character values, then change the `SELECT` to:

```
SELECT pc.*, ssc.*,
       (case when ssc.category_id is not null then '1' else '0' end) AS checked
```

Comment: Many thanks! Yes I needed the numeric values - I am not sure why I had them wrapped in quotation marks.